# "Placeholder does not exist in current context"

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to make a Navigation bar in Xamarin. I created a Context view with an x:name of Placeholder in my MainPage.xaml and when I go to call it in the xaml.cs page it says "Placeholder does not exist in current context" Bear in mind I am really new to Xamarin. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

MainPage.xaml

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentView x:Name="PlaceHolder" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="#DCDCDC" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        void Icon1_Tapped (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var page = new HomePage();
            PlaceHolder.ContentView = page.Content;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your file is called MainPage, but the class is HomePage?  That's not inherently wrong, but it makes me think that your classes are not setup right.

Comment: what is the value of x:Class in MainPage.xaml?

Comment: Hi Jason thanks for your reply. I just Wrote "MainPage" for simplicity sake, Apologies for that. Everything is done in  HomePage. The two instances of "PlaceHolder" are the only two in the whole project. The same goes for "x" I have no other instance of it.

Comment: please post the entire contents of the XAML and it's code behind

Answer (score 0):

Your `Page` class is simply missing the call to `InitializeComponent`. That is a method call to the partial class of the page which will internally do some processing for the XAML file (more information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/get-started-with-xaml?tabs=windows#anatomy-of-a-xaml-file)).

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    } 

    void Icon1_Tapped (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var page = new HomePage();
        PlaceHolder.ContentView = page.Content;

    }
}
```

Also please make sure the xaml file has the class type correctly set. In case you are using a `ContentPage`, you should have something like this:

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="YourNamespace.HomePage">

<!-- your content -->

</ContentPage
```